# Windows: How do I recognize that someone has access to my PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, security

I'm a Windows user (Windows 7 and 8.1).

How can I see that somebody has access to my system and how do I block this?

I mean both scenarios:

1. Some person somehow knows my password and can access my system directly (not online)
2. Someone connects remotely

Comment: Case 1:  Change your password and don't tell anyone what it is.  Use a password randomizer to get a good password.  Case 2: Firewall  Configure windows firewall to block it.  Get a hardware firewall if that is not enough.

Comment: @cybernard Thanks, but if it is case 2, how do I see that someone was there?

Comment: You **might** be able to check for suspicious logins and other events in the event viewer. Does the event viewer show you were logged in when you were asleep or not home?  Otherwise it could be a very time consuming process of examining file dates and logs.  Obviously use several antivirus scanners to make sure your clean.